# Novel where light sail cuts throat and main character uses body of a ballpoint pen for tracheotomy

Tags: story-identification, novel

"Young adult" novel involving a light sail that cuts someone's throat and the protagonist uses a ballpoint pen as an air tube so he can breathe.  Probably had the word "star" in the title.  It might have involved a young humanoid alien too.

Comment: I am so sorry. I read that when I was little but I have no idea the name or author. The earth boy and the alien girl are in a solar sail race around Saturn's rings. The solar sail ships look like earth boats with a silver sail, unfortunately razor sharp. The girl gets her throat cut, and the boy inserts the barrel of his ballpoint pen as an impromptu tracheotomy.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this book is "Starship on Saddle Mountain" by Atlantis Hallam. I remember the tracheotomy using a ball-point pen during a race around Saturn, but don't own the book and haven't read it in decades, so I can't quote any of it.

The ebook is available on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007E1S78).

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the one I was thinking about. I recognize the book cover.

Comment: @WinchellChung Are you the OP?

Comment: No, I am no OP. Should I delete my comment?

Comment: No, it was just confusing, that was all.